# BigQuery GUI only showing 1 space when the data actually contains multiple spaces

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

During the processing of Google Analytics Premium data, applying a regex to the data in Dataflow, I ran into the following issue:

Applying the regex: `.*xxx yyy.*` to a field containing the STRING: `xxx yyy` in the BigQuery GUI, didn't return `true`, while it should have.

I double checked my Dataflow code and the BigQuery data, but wasn't able to find the issue right away.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to how the data is represented in the BigQuery GUI. When running the exact same query using the BigQuery command line tool (`bq query`), the results showed that the **actual** data stored was not `xxx yyy` but `xxx  yyy` (containing two instead of one space), so it might be useful to double check your data there when running into a similar issue.

After doing some extra digging I found [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906060) on the Google issue tracker. You can stay up to date on the status of it by starring it.